# How to avoid groups of characters that might or not appear/interfere in a regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm experiencing a bit of a rippled carpet case with a regular expression.

The string in it's raw form that is being processed looks something like this:

```
1. [8] S Wawrinka (SUI) vs. A Golubev (KAZ)  2. D Sela (ISR) vs. J Nieminen (FIN)  3. S Giraldo (COL) vs. S Querrey (USA)  4. A Falla (COL) vs. M Kukushkin (KAZ)  5. I Karlovic (CRO) vs. [32] I Dodig (CRO)  6. [WC] S Johnson (USA) vs. A Mannarino (FRA)  7. [14] M Youzhny (RUS) vs. JL Struff (GER)  8. A Gonzalez (COL) vs. [3] D Ferrer (ESP)  9. [7] T Berdych (CZE) vs. A Nedovyesov (KAZ)  10. N Mahut (FRA) vs. M Ebden (AUS)H2H RR2*  11. [Q] D Thiem (AUT) vs. J Sousa (POR)  12. J Monaco (ARG) vs. [23] E Gulbis (LAT)  13. J Hajek (CZE) vs. [Q] D Dzumhur (BIH)
```

I'm not trying to make it as hard as possible to read but this is the exact output spit out from the HTML.
What I'm trying to match is this (example from aforementioned output):

```
 S Wawrinka (SUI) vs. A Golubev (KAZ)
```

or

```
 I Karlovic (CRO) vs. I Dodig (CRO)
```

or

```
 J Hajek (CZE) vs. D Dzumhur (BIH)
```

Notice that in the last two I've had to do some clean-up of a few bracketed char groups.

So basically I want to have all of the records in this long string. (a record is being identified by having a vs., so if there are 12 vs.'s in that string there should be 12 records. (they are matched in the expected output on both sides of it so that part is not a worry of mine)

In the 3 examples I've shown I gave out examples of what I'm trying to ignore. The characters that might appear that I'm trying to avoid are put in a pair of brackets on whatever side of the vs and are either: ( [WC], [Q], [LL], [12], [1], [28] )

Things that never change:

- vs. is guaranteed to be there for each record
- the junk characters are always in brackets and appear before the either names
- the overall records always keeps it's format

Something that might make the matching tricky is that the initial might be the same as one of the junk characters ( Q, W).

I've tried several expressions, pretty much all of them only achieve partial matching which is as good as none. Perhaps the most successful was:

```
       qr /
        ([A-Z]{1,2}   # Initials
        \s?
        [A-Za-z\']+   # Last name
        -?            # in case of hyphenated name
        \s?
        [A-Za-z\.]?   # two namer
        \s?
        \([A-Z]{3}\)  # country code
        \s?
        vs[.]?        # vs.
        \s?
        [^\]]\]?      # optional unwanted characters
        \s?
        [A-Z]{1,2}    
        \s?
        [A-Za-z\']+
        -?
        \s?
        [A-Za-z\.]*
        \s?
        \([A-Z]{3}\))
        /sx
```

I could pretty much match everything and then just clean up what I don't want but I  want a one-go clean solution.

Comment: You should probably remove (?:\\[.+\\]), makes it a lot easier to parse the rest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is getting rid of the distracting stuff:

```
# $t = "1. [8] S Waw....
my $re_name = qr/\b\w \w+ [(]\w+[)]/;
$t =~ s/\[[^\]]*\]//g; $t =~ s/ +/ /g;  # remove squared stuff
print "$1 vs. $2\n" while $t =~ /($re_name) vs[.] ($re_name)/g;
```

Comment: This does what is supposed to do and I'll end up using as a filter for a simpler expression to the one in the OP.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest to you the following algorithm:

1. Split your string by the pattern `[0-9]+\.`. This will give you all the records. (You'll have to discard the first empty item.)
2. Split each item by the string `vs.`. This will give you both contestants.
3. Parse the name, nation, etc. of each contestant using a much simpler regex.

Comment: I've thought about this. I think it would result in even more work since I'm using the names (which could be in different formats) for some pretty meticulous other stuff afterwards. I don't understand the first step of your algorithm.

Comment: @user3046061 The first step simply refers to calling the `split` function with the regular expression `[0-9]+\.`, like this: `split(/[0-9]+[.]/, $text)`. This will yield you all records that are enumerated.

Comment: That's actually a useful step. On one of my previous attempts I was having problems when I was matching stuff greedily, having multiple records get through, this would definitely change the picture a little.

Comment: @user3046061 It would also simplify your long regular expression and improve understandability (and maintainability).

Comment: Readability is second to the matching being fully functioning in this case. It has to be specific, but I agree with your point generally. I have to accept the first answer because it is complete. Yours was useful as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quit trying to cram it into one statement.
Since you don't care about the bracketed info, just clobber that with a substitute operation
    s/\[.*?\]//g;
first, and then split on
    /\d+\./